# How to start a scheduled job using Quartz.Net?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I created a .Net 5 worker service application and installed the `Quartz.AspNetCore` package.

I want to run code based on a cron expression, e.g. every 5 minutes. I created a class `MyJob` implementing `Ijob` and register it during DI setup

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services
                    .AddQuartz(quartzConfiguration =>
                    {
                        quartzConfiguration.ScheduleJob<MyJob>(jobConfiguration =>
                        {
                            jobConfiguration.WithCronSchedule("20/20 0 0 ? * * *"); // Every 20 seconds starting at second 20
                        });
                    })
                    .AddQuartzHostedService(quartzConfiguration => // I think this code is useful ?
                    {
                        quartzConfiguration.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
                    })
                    .AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
```

But the job itself never executes. When calling `quartzConfiguration.AddJob<MyJob>()` doesn't give me access to the method `.WithCronSchedule()`.

So how can I tell Quartz to register a job and execute it based on a cron expression?

Comment: Just to clarify, this should run at 12am? There aren't any exceptions or anything? The `IJob` code is never hit?

Comment: @RowanFreeman would you mind explaining the time "12am"? I took the cron expression from here https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html and get the same cron string

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that the OP actually waited until 12am for the job to run. It looks like the hour component is zero, which would equal 12am (00:00:20 and 00:00:40).

Comment: @RowanFreeman so you think `20/20 0 0 ? * * *` does not start after 20 seconds and then executes every 20 seconds? Maybe the generator page isn't obvious to me then ...

Comment: @RowanFreeman ok it seems the cron expression is wrong, I tested with `0 */2 * ? * *` (every 2 min) and that worked ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron expression `20/20 0 0 ? * * *` means "every 20 seconds, after the first 20 seconds, on the first minute of the first hour.

So basically, `00:00:20` and `00:00:40`, or 20 seconds past midnight and 40 seconds past midnight.

Check to see if this is the cron you intended. Everything else looks correct.